# Cast Flask form value to int

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a form that posts a `personId` int to Flask. However, `request.form['personId']` returns a string. Why isn't Flask giving me an int?

I tried casting it to an int, but the route below either returned a 400 or 500 error. How can I get I get the `personId` as an int in Flask?

```
@app.route('/getpersonbyid', methods = ['POST'])
def getPersonById():
    personId = (int)(request.form['personId'])
    print personId
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

HTTP form data is a string, Flask doesn't receive any information about what type the client intended each value to be. So it parses all values as strings.

You can call `int(request.form['personId'])` to get the id as an int. If the value isn't an int though, you'll get a `ValueError` in the log and Flask will return a 500 response. And if the form didn't have a `personId` key, Flask will return a 400 error.

```
personId = int(request.form['personId'])
```

Instead you can use the [`MultiDict.get()` method](http://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) and pass `type=int` to get the value if it exists and is an int:

```
personId = request.form.get('personId', type=int)
```

Now `personId` will be set to an integer, *or* `None` if the field is not present in the form or cannot be converted to an integer.

---

There are also some issues with your example route.

A route should `return` something, otherwise it will raise a 500 error. `print` outputs to the console, it doesn't return a response. For example, you could return the id again:

```
@app.route('/getpersonbyid', methods = ['POST'])
def getPersonById():
    personId = int(request.form['personId'])
    return str(personId)  # back to a string to produce a proper response
```

The parenthesis around `int` are not needed in Python and in this case are ignored by the parser. I'm assuming you are doing something meaningful with the `personId` value in the view; otherwise using `int()` on the value is a little pointless.