# Passing arguments to a Flask Application/Celery Task Queue

Tags: python, curl, flask, request, celery

I have a Flask app that uses Celery to run tasks.  To start the environment I start a redis server (to store results), then Celery, then my app (python app.py).  To kick off a job, I want to issue a POST request with cURL, and I want to pass in a parameter, which will be stored in the key-value:

curl ... -X POST -d '{"key": "value"}'

How does my Python program receive that parameter?  Normally you'd use argv when you're just running python app.py, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You would curl to the address with post variables.
app.py would try to parse if the request type is POST AND to parse the post variables.

**post request**

```
curl ... -X POST -d '{"type": "sendemail","who":"foo@bar.42"}'
curl ... -X POST -d '{"type": "sendsms","who":"+1297581234"}'
```

**app.js (I don't know flask)**

```
if request.type == 'POST':
    if post['type'] == 'sendemail':
        celery.createjob('sendemail',post['who'])
    elif post['type'] == 'sendsms'
        celery.createjob('sendsms',post['who'])
```

learn more about [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#variable-rules) and refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551526/retrieving-specific-post-data-in-flask)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a POST request, then you can use [requests.post()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)
While on the receiving end. You can use [request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) provided by flask.
For example: 
On the client end:

```
from requests import post
import json
payload = {'product_id': 'B014F6U5N6', 'website_name': 'amazonIN', 'url': 'xyz'}
r = post("http://localhost:5000", json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
print r.text
```

On the receiving end:

```
from flask import request
product_id = request.json['product_id']
url = request.json['url']
website_name = request.json['website_name']
```