# Ajax post returns given url instead of posted data

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I have this html (+ JS) code:

```
<div id="input_form">
   <fieldset>
      <form id="myform" method="post" action="">
         seq: <input type="text" name="seq" id = "seq"><br><br>
         aa: <input type="text" name="prot" id = "prot"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id = "submitID" value="translate">
      </form>
   </fieldset>
</div>
<script>
   $("#submitID").click(function() {
      document.body.style.background = 'red';
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/<seq>",
         data: 'message',
         success: function(data) {  
            document.body.style.background = 'green';
            document.getElementById("prot").value = data;
            alert(data); // show response from the python script.
         },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.responseText);
         }
      });
      return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
   });
</script>
```

Further I have this python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return render_template("afvink1.html")


@app.route("/<seq>",methods=['POST','GET'])
def seq(seq):
    return seq

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However instead of seeing the `message` string in the `prot` textfield I see the url: `<seq>`in my `prot` textfield. I do not get any errors/exceptions. I tried to change the url to `<seq>` which resulted in the same bug.

Comment: Hmmm..,I wonder if the issue is with the brackets <>

Comment: Oh...I see... your code should be called as url: '/message' not '/<seq>'... the seq is a placeholder on the back end but must have the actual value in the Ajax call.

Comment: That is assuming you really want to return whatever comes after the slash

Comment: If you want your data in the back end then you use the request.form... see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551526/retrieving-specific-post-data-in-flask

Comment: But what should I use as url call? Just setting it to "/" will not work? @FernandoZ

Comment: you can use URL as `/seq` and here also `@app.route("/seq"`.  then as Fernando suggested, get POST values by request.form.

Comment: This will return seq in the prot textbox instead of the desired "message" string @Pradeepb

Comment: It will show whatever you send from the backend right? currently, you are returning `seq`.  I think you have to work on your backend code. try printing `request.form` in your backend code. and see what you get.

Comment: no it's not returning something from the backend it returns the same value as the my url. If I use /<seq> it will return <seq> if I use seq as url it will return seq. It think it should work without using request.form

Comment: So what is desired output? It should return value `message` which you are sending from your ajax POST request right?

Comment: I also tried to remove the "data" tag and use url: "message" however this gave the error: URL was not found on the server @Pradeepb

Comment: Yes (I will replace message later by some textfield value) thankyou for thinking with me! @Pradeepb

Comment: I fixed it! using the url approach I mentioned above @Pradeepb However I can only post one variable then I think

Comment: Yes. That's because you doing it wrong. As I said earlier, you need to work on your backend code. that URL approach you using works for only one argument. If you want to send many arguments then you have to use URL as `/seq` and get values using `request.form`.

Comment: Could you please give a code example, I'm just new in all this @Pradeepb

Comment: Check the answer I have posted below.

Comment: In essence <seq> is a dynamic value in your route which arrives on your back end as a function parameter...the data is part of the post. <seq> is part of the URL . For example if you had a URL like this /Orders/<order>. the  parameter could be called like this /Orders/12345 where 12345 would change each time to indicate the order number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below answer to fulfill your requirements.

```
@app.route("/seq", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def seq():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form)
        return request.form['message']
    else:
        // Do Stuff here for GET request
        // return ''
```

You `ajax` POST request will be like below:

```
<script>
$("#submitID").click(function() {
    document.body.style.background = 'red';
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/seq",
            data: {
                message: 'message' // you can send other parameters here.
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
               document.body.style.background = 'green';
               document.getElementById("prot").value = data;
               alert(data); // show response from the python script.
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
         });
    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
</script>
```

As I had explained in the comments, the issue is with your route(the way you specified in Flask backend).

Comment: wow thankyou so much! I've been trying to achieve this for two full days now

Answer (score 1):

The `<seq>` means it's a dynamic part of the url. And the `seq` will be passed to the view function. You write `<seq>` in your ajax code. So the `seq`(parameter of view function) will be `<seq>`. And the view function return it to your as response data.

Comment: What do you advice to use as url then? I tried to use url: "/" however this won't work either

Comment: You should look through the [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) of Flask.