# Why is my form deserialized as Mutlidict with strings instead of integers in flask

Tags: python, flask, deserialization

I am sending a form from an html page, some (but not all) input appear to be string instead of integer. 
This form has 60+ inputs.

I could manually cast every number input as a int in my dict but I dont know all the input names to cast.

I have a flask template as

```html
<!doctype html>
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('result') }}">
    <div>
        <p>nb_ref</p>
        <input type="number" name="nb_ref" value=1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>type_client</p>
        <input type="text" name="type_client" value="P">
    </div>
    ...more inputs removed for clarity

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Go</button>
</form>
```

I output the response here

```
@app.route("/result", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    error = None
    select = request.form.to_dict()
    pp(select)
```

which gives me in my logs

```
{'SST_si_second_devis': '0',
...more items removed for clarity
 'nb_ref': '1',
 'type_client': 'P'}
```

I wish to have an outputed dict as the following

```
{'SST_si_second_devis': 0,
...more items removed for clarity
 'nb_ref': 1,
 'type_client': 'P'}
```

**edit:**

the solution of the question here [Cast Flask form value to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551526/cast-flask-form-value-to-int) would require me to know which input is actually a string or integer before hand, which is not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all of them and cast to `int` if possible.

```
for key, val in select.items():
    try:
        select[key] = int(val)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: I've edited the question : I do not know which one should be an int and which one a string

Comment: With my answer, anything that can be cast as an `int` will be. Everything else will be left as is. Aside from that there's nothing else to be done per the question as is.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this out

Comment: great, it worked