# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, html, flask, typeerror

I have been working on this forex converter mini app for a small project, which should contain a specific amount of libraries etc, This project consists on using Python with Flask only. No other language should be involved. So far I think I am in the right way but when I'm trying to set up a:

```py
request.form.get()
```

to retrieve a value from a specific input element on my html file (I have 2 more but those work perfectly fine)
It throws me back the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/app.py", line 45, in convert_page
    final_curr = currency.convert(from_curr, to_curr, amount)
  File "/home/sam/Forex Converter/Converter!/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/forex_python/converter.py", line 90, in convert
    return float(amount)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here's my code so far:

**Python:**

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, session, url_for
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    TESTING=True,
    SECRET_KEY='192b9bdd22ab9ed4d12e236c78afcb9a393ec15f71bbf5dc987d54727823bcbf'
)
currency = CurrencyRates()

#amount = int(input("Enter the amount: "))

#from_curr = input("From Currency: ").upper()
#to_curr = input("To Currency: ").upper()


#print(from_curr, "To", to_curr, amount)

#result = currency.convert(from_curr, to_curr, amount)

#print("Conversion amount:", result)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Show homepage."""

    # This keep track of how many times we visit a page.
    session['count'] = session.get('count', 0) + 1

    return render_template("body.html")



@app.route('/convert', methods=['GET','POST'])
def convert_page():
    
    """Shows conversion area"""

    amount = request.form.get('amount')
    from_curr = request.form.get('from_curr')
    to_curr = request.form.get('to_curr')

    #We save final value into final_curr
    final_curr = currency.convert(from_curr, to_curr, amount)
    
    return render_template("convert.html", display_result=final_curr)
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1> Convert your coins here!!</h1>

<h2>Conversion</h2>

<form action="{{url_for('convert_page') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter amount" id="amount"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="From currency" id="from_curr"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="To currency" id="to_curr">
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>

<p id="result_paragraph">{{ display_result }}</p>
```

I have tried to set up the request to only accept integers like this:

```py
amount = int(request.form.get('amount'))
```

That didn't work and gives me back another error, I may be confused because it expects a string or an int for the value but isn't `request.args` supposed to retrieve values as a "string" no matter what we pass in?? or if I'm setting the request to accept integers incorrectly?? Also tried to do try and catch but didn't work either.

With this I'm basically expecting to retrieve whatever value the user submits on the input, to be more specific an int because this amount will be used to determine a currency rate. If i print the logic into the console it seems to work but with flask I'm having trouble.

Comment: Not familiar with Flask but I do not think including `SECRET_KEY` seems to be a good idea in the code. Please consider changing this.

Comment: Supposedly they key is used to gain access to the debug console it provides chrome when flask throws the error on my browser, without it, if the project was public anyone would be able to change stuff on it. That's what I was taught.

Comment: This may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551526/cast-flask-form-value-to-int). I would also look to see if changing input type to "number" instead of "text" would make a difference. Furthermore, I would try logging the amount to make sure you're getting the value you're expecting and work you're way up from there.

Comment: @FrantzPaul Thanks for the info! Unfortunately they didn't work as we would expect them to. I think the main problem resides on the converter library, as noted on the traceback error it is expecting "amount" to be an integer. However somehow flask is not retrieving the value as either string or int.

Comment: Based on the traceback, it looks like float is receiving a NoneType, which makes me wonder if the amount is getting set. Are you able to confirm that "amount" is being set by the form before the converter library does its stuff?

Comment: @FrantzPaul Thanks for the help! As of today I already found the issue, apparently when calling forms in flask you must call them by the "name" tag, not ids. Which is weird but that's what worked for me. I'm getting more errors but my suspicions are that the API is down.